# Time Machine: Back up separate files to separate drives?

Tags: macos, backup, time-machine

Time Machine allows the use of multiple backup drives. However, any exclusions of files applies to all backup drives.

I would like to backup some files to one drive, and other files, to another drive. Is this possible within Time Machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible with Time Machine. You can use Time Machine for one drive, then use an alternative backup solution for the other files to the other drive.

Comment: Bummer, thanks for your help. I'll try CCC or others.